# How to use multiple rendering engines in rails action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to return both html fragment and json data in one request. (EDIT: I admit that the simplest solution is just splitting the request into two. But if there's a way I want to try.) So the code in my controller's action goes like following:

```
format.json {
  html = render html: { partial: 'shops/search/result_block.html', locals: { shops: @shops, conditions: @conditions } }
  json = render json: 'shops/search.json'
  render json: { html: html, json: json }
}
```

If I do this, rails warns like folloing:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

OK. I understand these methods are something more than just rendering string out of template engines.

I think what I need is something like:
calling rendering engines' methods directly or utilising core functionality of rendering engine - just need the formatted output as a string. And then just return the result as JSON. But how?!

Comment: I'm curious, have you tried using render_to_string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `render_to_string` in both cases for `HTML` and `JSON`, `Render` can be used only once in your action, otherwise you will get `double render error`:

```
html_data = render_to_string(partial: 'shops/search/result_block.html', :layout => false, :locals => { shops: @shops, conditions: @conditions })
json_data = render_to_string(partial: 'shops/search.json')
render json: { html: html_data, json: json_data }
```

Check [Here](https://coderwall.com/p/ov8eha/render-an-html-partial-inside-a-json-request)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't render multiple times
2. If you decide to render a json format, you can't insert any html in it.

You could do it only if all your html is in a string like this: `{"json":{"json_stuff":value}, "html": "<html><body></body></html"}`

You could use [JsonBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to render your json view and inside your viewfile.json.jbuilder do a partial render of your html file in text.

3. Advice : If you're here right now, it's probably because there is a problem in your conception, you may want to split this call in two actions.